# Return a keycode when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulate left and right arrow key event with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516600/simulate-left-and-right-arrow-key-event-with-javascript)

I want that when I click on a button a keycode is issued. For example there's a button somewhere on a webpage. When you click on this button, the keycode <kbd>j</kbd> is issued (Or maybe a shortcut <kbd>cmd+j</kbd>). 
How can I do this?

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/832121/1953933)

Comment: The answer depends on what you want the "j" keypress to do.

Comment: You can't just pretend the user typed anything, like ctrl-alt-del, or alt-f4,... What do you need to do exactly?