# JavaScript Simulate Arrow Key Event

Tags: javascript, arrow-keys

I was on http://threesjs.com/ , thinking about how I might implement a learning agent to play. Somehow this led me to the following question: Is there a command I can type into the JavaScript console (perhaps after writing a function) that will simulate any of the arrow keys? I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516600/simulate-left-and-right-arrow-key-event-with-javascript) that I was unable to successfully use in my given situation, probably due to my inexperience with JS.

Thanks SO.

Comment: I don't think it's the arrow keys we are thinking about, just the function or code that runs that is ran when they are pressed. So if we had for example: `if(e.keycode == 37) moveLeft();` we can just call `moveLeft()`.