# Selenium sendKeys() different behaviour for Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is simple snippet of code.

```
@FindBy(className = "element-to-press")
private WebElement elementToPress;

// some other code

Keys move = Keys.ARROW_DOWN;
gridContainer.sendKeys(move);
```

In **Firefox** everything works fine.

In **Chrome** I've got `"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element"` error

**Safari** does not react for sendKeys()

Also I've tried to use another approach:

```
Keys move = Keys.ARROW_DOWN;
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click(); // to focus on element
actions.sendKeys(move).perform();
```

This code fixed **Chrome** `"cannot focus element"` error, but browser still does not react for `Keys.ARROW_DOWN/Keys.ARROW_UP/Keys.ARROW_LEFT/Keys.ARROW_RIGHT` events

Safari and Firefox do not react for sendKeys() as well.

I cannot understand what is going on and how I can make my code run for all this browsers.

**Environment**:

- OS X 10.9.5
- Latest version of Chrome/Safari/Firefox
- Selenium version 2.44.0

**UPD:**

Update Selenium to version 2.46.

Works for Chrome and Firefox now.

But still have an issue with Safari:`org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session.`

***UPD2:***

I have Safari browser extension installed.
[image]

Comment: Use Selenium 2.46 and chromedriver 2.16 [from here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: Update Selenium to version 2.46. Works for Chrome and Firefox now.  
But still have an issue with Safari.

Comment: Have you installed the [Safari Driver Extension](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/SafariDriver.safariextz) Read abt that [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver#getting-started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in chat you want to automate [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/)

As a workaround I've written [Javascript based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5517065/3122133) to send Arrow KeyEvents.And It worked on all browsers

All you want to do is send arrow keys no need to click element at all [and find element ,unless you create a algorithm to play based on values)

You got me into this.The following will play game with 200(50 x 4) different moves for 3 browsers

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    play(new FirefoxDriver());
    play(new SafariDriver());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/Apple/Documents/chromedriver");
    play(new ChromeDriver());
}

public static void play(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.get("http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048");
    driver.findElement(By.className("restart-button")).click();
    String script = "fireKey(arguments[0]);\n"
            + "function fireKey(arrow)\n"
            + "{\n"
            + "    var key;\n"
            + "    switch (arrow.toLowerCase())\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "        case \"left\":\n"
            + "            key = 37;\n"
            + "            break;\n"
            + "        case \"right\":\n"
            + "            key = 39;\n"
            + "            break;\n"
            + "        case \"up\":\n"
            + "            key = 38;\n"
            + "            break;\n"
            + "        case \"down\":\n"
            + "            key = 40;\n"
            + "            break;\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "    if (document.createEventObject)\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "        var eventObj = document.createEventObject();\n"
            + "        eventObj.keyCode = key;\n"
            + "        document.documentElement.fireEvent(\"onkeydown\", eventObj);\n"
            + "    } else if (document.createEvent)\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "        var eventObj = document.createEvent(\"Events\");\n"
            + "        eventObj.initEvent(\"keydown\", true, true);\n"
            + "        eventObj.which = key;\n"
            + "        document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(eventObj);\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "} ";

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    //use left,right,up,down for arrow keys
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        js.executeScript(script, "left");
        js.executeScript(script, "right");
        js.executeScript(script, "up");
        js.executeScript(script, "down");
    }
    System.out.println("Score :" + driver.findElement(By.className("score-container")).getText());
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2**

Refer the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31564836/3122133) answer for fullcode

---

**Update 1**

SafariDriver Extension doesn't work with Selenium 2.46.I've tried it and you have to downgrade the Selenium to [2.45](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.45/) as SafariDriver Extension for 2.46 is not released yet.Refer this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/631)

So as of now go with Selenium 2.45

---

**Initial Answer**

You have to install SafariDriver [Extension](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/SafariDriver.safariextz) Manually

As per [SafariWiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver#getting-started)

> Starting with Selenium 2.45.0, you must manually install the
>   SafariDriver browser extension. Simply open the latest copy of
>   SafariDriver.safariextz in Safari and click the "install" button. Once
>   installed, writing a test for Safari is just as straightforward as
>   using the FirefoxDriver

Comment: I have SafariDriver Extension installed. The problem is that driver could not start a new session: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session.

Comment: @art_tykh Updated the answer check it

Comment: Downgrading to Selenium 2.45 solved the issue with browser launch. But Safari still does not react for sendKeys() events. Do you know what is the best way to send "Keys.ARROW_RIGHT" for SafariDriver ?

Comment: @art_tykh You want to sendKeys to element or to driver?

Comment: I want to sendKeys to element. 
For **FirefoxDriver** I do it via: `element.sendKeys(key)`;


  For **ChromeDriver** via: 
            `Actions actions = new Actions(driver());
            actions.moveToElement(element).click();
            actions.sendKeys(key).perform();`


  For **SafariDriver** - none of above is working

Comment: Instead of action For all do like this: `element.click();element.sendKeys(key);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83960/discussion-between-art-tykh-and-madhan).

Comment: @art_tykh I've posted the code just use this and tell whether it is working or not